# reactjs highcharts reference for reload

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to dynamically set the series data of highcharts when the user clicks a button. I need the reference of the highchart but not sure how to get get the reference to call the series[0].setData function.

Here is my sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-rtlie

Here is the code -

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import drilldow from "highcharts/modules/drilldown";
//import HighchartsReact from "./HighchartsReact.js";
import PieChart from "highcharts-react-official";
drilldow(Highcharts);
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: "pie"
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [{ y: 100, name: "Female" }, { y: 50, name: "Male" }]
    }
  ]
};
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      chart_options: null
    };
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  onFilterClickHandler = () => {
    console.log("onfilterclickhandler");
    // need chart reference to call the series.setdata function
    //chart.series[0].setData
  };

  render() {
    const key = 1;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>
            For female click here &nbsp;
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={key}
              onClick={this.onFilterClickHandler}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <h2>Highcharts</h2>
        <PieChart highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the series data by `setState` method:

```
onFilterClickHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    chart_options: {
      series: [
        {
          data: [...]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

---

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-wd9m1

---

Or get the chart reference and call `setData` directly on a series:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    ...

    this.afterChartCreated = this.afterChartCreated.bind(this);
  }

  afterChartCreated(chart) {
    this.internalChart = chart;
  }

  onFilterClickHandler = () => {
    ...
    this.internalChart.series[0].setData([50, 50]);
  };

  render() {
    const key = 1;
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <PieChart
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={options}
          callback={this.afterChartCreated}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-c8yvg

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-get-a-chart-instance